# Trip planning algorithm

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, interview-questions

I was presented with an interview question described as follows:

Receiving an `int[] A` of cities, where each `A[i]` has an appeal value. We want to plan our trip based on the highest appeal possible, taking in mind that is calculated as follows `A[i] + A[j] + (i - j)`. This means the appeal values of 2 cities summed, plus their distance.

Function signature:

`public static int solution(int[] A);`

The constraints were the following:

- N is an integer within [1, 100,000]
- A[i] is an integer within [-1,000,000,000, 1,000,000,000]

Using the **same value** is a possible valid solution, so for example, if we have `A = {1, 3, -3};` this should return `6` as visiting city `A[0]` twice gives the max appeal value `A[0] + A[0] + (0 - 0) = 6`.

So given that, a possible solution is the same value twice, I did not found other solution than:

```
int highestAppeal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        int currentAppeal = A[i] + A[j] + (i - j);
        highestAppeal = currentAppeal > highestAppeal ? currentAppeal : highestAppeal;
    }
}

return highestAppeal;
```

This solution was marked as pretty bad. I realize that a \$O(n^2)\$ solution is far from efficient, but in this case, I did not see how to improve it. Later on, I thought about sorting `A` values in descending order and, for repeated values, using indexes in ascending order. But I don't see that going forward.

What would be a better and more efficient solution for this?

Comment: Well, I've added the expected function signature, so it is clear that an ```int``` is expected as result.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that.

Comment: I deleted my answer. I've come to the conclusion that this was a trick question with a purpose of finding out if you notice bad requirements and are able to ask clarifications.

Comment: I had lots of things to ask clarification for, but they sent me as an assignment through a site. I had 2 tasks which I had to do in 1 hour. This was one of them.

Comment: So, had no contact or any way of asking anything.

Comment: You dodged a bullet. The task was incredibly badly set up. Good luck with the next application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I asked the interviewers themselves for an efficient solution to this problem, and I finally got one:

```
int maxStart = A[0];
int maxEnd = A[0];

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if ((A[i] - i) > maxStart) {
        maxStart = A[i] - i;
    }

    if ((A[i] + i) > maxEnd) {
        maxEnd = A[i] + i;
    }
}

return maxEnd + maxStart;
```

So this is the O(n) solution they gave me, which I found pretty beautiful to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking this more, there are three things affecting the appeal.

- A[i]
- A[j]
- i - j

Since `A[i] + A[j]` is the same as `A[j] + A[i]`, you don't need to traverse the whole array in the inner loop.

Since the third component increases the appeal only when `j < i`, you can restrict the inner loop to run from 0 to i.

You also need to take into account the fact that all cities may have negative appeal. Integer.MIN_VALUE is safe initial value, as the lowest valid value (2 * -1000000000 - 100000) is still greater than that.

Using Math.max would have been more readable.

```
    int highestAppeal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            final int currentAppeal = A[i] + A[j] + (i - j);
            highestAppeal = Math.max(highestAppeal, currentAppeal);
        }
    }

    return highestAppeal;
```

And you can't overestimate the value of commented code in an interview answer.